# CSS media query with max-width: 1024px not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting a CSS media query to work properly with max-width: 1024px. My goal is to have a different layout for devices with bigger screens, so I'm using the following media query:

first page

> ```
> <meta charset="utf-8">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
> <title>Food Menu</title>
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css"> </head> <body>
>
> <div class="headertext">
>     Mexican Food
> </div>
>
> <div class="recipelist">
>     <p>Recipes</p>
>     <a class="recipes" href="./recipe1/index.html">Enchiladas</a>
>     <a class="recipes" href="./recipe2/index.html">Sopes</a>
>     <a class="recipes" href="./recipe3/index.html">Flan</a>
>     <a class="recipes" href="./recipe4/index.html">Tres Leches</a>
>     <a class="recipes" href="./recipe5/index.html">Tostadas</a>
>     <a class="recipes" href="./recipe6/index.html">Pozole</a>
> </div> </body> </html>
> ```

second page

> ```
> <meta charset="utf-8">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
> <title>Enchilada's Recipe</title>
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../master.css"> </head> <body>
> <div id = "all">
>     <div id = "header">
>     <h1>Enchiladas</h1>
>     </div>
>     <div id = "left">
>     <h2>Video</h2>
>     <div>
>         <iframe 
>   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CjoVxMSdfKg"></iframe>
>     </div>
>     </div>
>     <div id = "right">
>     <h2 >Recipe</h2>
>     <ul>
>         <li>
>             INGREDIENTS
>             1 lb ground beef (I used 97/3 lean to fat ratio)
>             1/4 cup diced onions 
>             2 garlic cloves minced
>             1/2 tsp ground cumin
>             1/2 tsp salt</li>
>         <li>pepper to taste
>             14  corn tortillas
>             1/3 cup oil (for softening corn tortillas)
>             12 oz cheddar cheese (or Colby jack cheese)</li>
>     </ul>
>     </div>
>     <div id = "footer">
>     <h3><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjoVxMSdfKg">Enchilada
> ```
>
> Video
>
> ```
>    <button class="button button1" onclick="window.location.href='../index.html'">Main Page</button>
> ```

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  button{
    transform: translateY(-63vh);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button1 {
        background-color: white; 
        color: black; 
        border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
      }
      
      .button1:hover {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
      }
      
body{
    background-image: url(./images/img2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

.headertext{
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 9%;
    height: 180px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translateY(1vh);
}

.recipelist {
    max-width: 10%;
    height: 300px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translateY(10vh);
}

a{
    color: orange;
}
a:hover{
    color: greenyellow;
}

/*jello layout start*/
#all {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    color: orange;
    transform: translateY(15vh);
    width: 990px;
    height: 605px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
   }
   #header {
    
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 989px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 1em;
   }
   #left {
    
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    clear: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    padding-right: .5em;
   }

   iframe{
    width: 305px;
    height: 331px;
   }

   li{
    transform: translateY(-1vh);
    font-size: 25px;
   }


   #right {
    
    float: left;
    width: 672.9px;
    height: 400px;
    padding-left: .5em;
   }

   #footer {
    
    width: 990px;
    height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px double black;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    clear: both;
   }
/*jello layout end*/
}
```

here's my other media query

```
@media (max-width: 320px){
    body{
        background-image: url(./images/img1.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }


        button{
            transform: translateY(-1vh);
            background-color: orange;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
        
            .button1 {
                background-color: white; 
                color: black; 
                border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
              }
              
              .button1:hover {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
              }

        .headertext{
            max-width: 75%;
            height: 130px;
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            color: white;
            font-size: 28px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 30px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .recipelist{
            max-width: 50%;
            height: 280px;
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            color: white;
            font-size: 28px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 30px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0 auto;
            transform: translateY(3vh);
        }

        /*jello layout start*/
        #all {
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            width: 315px;
            height: 270px;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 36%;
            left: 52%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translateX(-1vh);
          }
          

#header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 314px;
    height: 80px;
}

#left {
    display: inline-block;
    width:90px;
    clear: left;
    height: 105px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

iframe{
    width: 92px;
    height: 68px;
   }

   li{
    font-size: 9px;
    transform: translateY(-2vh);
   }

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 207px;
    height: 130px;
}


#footer {
    width: 314px;
    height: 144px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2{
    font-size: 10px;
}

h3{
    font-size: 12px;
}
/*jello layout end*/
```

However, this query seems to be ignored entirely, even when I resize my browser window to a bigger width. Instead, the styles for smaller screens continue to apply.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what might be causing this issue or how to fix it? Thanks in advance for your help!

I have checked that there are no conflicting styles or other media queries that might be overriding this one. And I need to use 1024px for this

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
Besides, you forgot to add the `@` for the second query so it could be a typo. Please make sure you double-check that.

Comment: that was a typo

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to add some HTML to a demo snippet as suggested above. CSS is meaningless without it.

Comment: Also, please format your code properly. Any good editor does this for you. It's difficult to interpret messy code. There must be a syntax issue in what's above because the Tidy button doesn't format it properly.

Comment: Not you've put all your code inside quotation blocks. That's not correct, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely, that the rules override each other and the one that comes later in the code will win.

The thing is you define one query for `max-width: 320px` which applies from `1px` up to `320px` and a query from `1px` up to `1024px`. So you define the area from `1px` to `320px` twice.

Instead of `max-width` use `min-width` for the `1024px`. This will then only apply to screens larger than `1024px`. From your description, this is what I think you want to achieve.

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>Test</body>
```

In the same way, the area between `320px` and `500px` for example could be addressed with:

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>Test</body>
```